# jui/datepicker dateformat issue

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker, yii2

I am using \yii\jui\DatePicker in my view.
when I provide input as 31/10/2017 it takes it as 31/Oct/2017. 
However, when I provide input as 01/10/2017 it takes it as 10/Jan/2017 instead of 01/oct/2017 .

How can I specify input date format.
My code for it is:

```
echo $form->field($model, 'target_end_date')->widget(\yii\jui\DatePicker::classname(), [
                'dateFormat' => 'php:d/M/Y',
                'options'=>['style'=>'width:250px;', 'class'=>'form-control','readOnly'=>'readOnly', 'placeholder'=>'Select end date.']
            ]);
```

Comment: My concern is not Jan or numeric 01. M concern is if first 2 digits are less than 13 then it is taken as month otherwise it is taken as day by datepicker

Answer (score 1):

dateFormat is no longer the part of clientOptions and should be specified as follows:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'target_end_date')->widget(\yii\jui\DatePicker::className(), [
    'dateFormat' => 'php:d-m-Y',
]); ?>
```

Or, an alternative in ICU format:

'`dateFormat' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',`

See official docs for https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-jui/doc/api/2.0/yii-jui-datepicker#$dateFormat-detail property.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Change your code

```
echo $form->field($model, 'target_end_date')->widget(\yii\jui\DatePicker::classname(), [
                'dateFormat' => 'php:d/M/Y',
                'options'=>['style'=>'width:250px;', 'class'=>'form-control','readOnly'=>'readOnly', 'placeholder'=>'Select end date.']
            ]);
```

To

```
echo $form->field($model, 'target_end_date')->widget(\yii\jui\DatePicker::classname(), [
                'dateFormat' => 'php:d/m/Y',
                'options'=>['style'=>'width:250px;', 'class'=>'form-control','readOnly'=>'readOnly', 'placeholder'=>'Select end date.']
            ]);
```

And for more date related formate refer below link.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php